# Indefinite determiners for introducing an item in plural as new information

Tags: indefinite-article, determiners

Oftentimes you would use an indefinite determiner (a(n), some, Ø) when introducing an item as new information. And I have been thinking of use of determiners when introducing a new item in plural.

In the following conversations, I feel B could say either some or Ø determiner (Ø article), and sound natural. What do you say?

[1]

> A: Okay, choose something from this box. Does everyone have something
>   in your hands?
>
> B: (1-1) Yes, I have some pens. (1-2) Yes, I have pens.

[2]

> (Showing weirdly-shaped pens to a friend)
>
> B: (2-1) These are some pens. (2-2) These are pens.

Comment: No determiner/article sounds better to my non-native ear. In the first sentence 1. - means you have a few pens, while, 2. - means you have an unknown amount of pens (few, some, a lot of, many, couple?).

Comment: @SovereignSun - Yes, 'some' is also a quantifier. It more defines the perimeter.

Answer (score 1):

> Okay, choose something from this box. Does everyone have something in your hands?

There are two things you can mean with this question.

- Choose one item from this box, any type.
- Choose one type of item from this box (implied if there is 1 item per type in box)

Zero article is used if you are talking about something as a type or category versus an actual instance of something.

The determiner *some X* implies that X is part of a group that is itself part of a bigger group.  It can typically mean "more than one X but not all X" or "a group of X that could be placed in a bigger group"

> Yes, I have some pens (I have more than one pen but I don't believe I have all the pens - these pens came from a bigger group of something)
>
> Yes, I have pens (as opposed to something of another type such as erasers, pencils, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Answers have slightly different meaning based on context. Let me use your answers in different conversations to show the difference:

```
"A: What do you have on your table? (person wants to know something general)"
"B: I have pens."
"C: I have oranges."
"D: I have glasses."
```

or:

```
"A: What do you see there?" (person doesn't see well so asks in general)
"B: These are pens."
"C: No, these are pencils."
```

Above are very simple portion of general information. Below are more specific.

```
"A: Do you have anything to write with?"
"B: I have some pens" (person is not sure if the pens are operable)
```

or:

```
"A: I have lost my favorite pen. (sad face)"
"B: These are some pens, check them out, maybe one is yours." (person presents bunch of pens but doesn't know if there is the lost one)
```

The other meaning is when "some" gives information about undefined quantity, then "I have some pens" implies that you have a part of all.